# Spectral analysis on polling data

Tags: discrete-signals

First-time questioner...

I'm writing an application (hobby/non-commercial, asp.net c#) to process polling data (answers to a single yes/no question) automatically collected from a website. The answers accumulate (yes = +1, no = -1) in a running total that ticks upwards and downwards over time. The application will display this data stream in a chart in real-time as answers are submitted, as well as - hopefully - provide some deeper analysis in, or near, real-time.

The goal is to track the time of each data point and get at any cyclical tendencies or directional movement over time. I'd like to try to do spectral analysis on the raw feed of data, which I understand is a naturally-occurring discrete-time sequence, one that's also non-equispaced in time since the data come in sporadically, like a political debate audience mashing yes and no buttons as they see fit through the course of the discussion.

My cursory initial investigation has led to me understand that linear shift/time-invariate systems generally require samples at integer spaced intervals (and that they *can* work for non-time-equispaced data, but care would need to be taken in the design and use of such systems). I'd also like to avoid interpolating between the discrete data points, as a workaround, so as not to make up information.

I'm optimistic this isn't an impossible dream, and that there's a way to process this data as it occurs naturally. **If so, would NFFT be the right set of tools to use? Is there a tool in particular, or some altogether different processing paradigm, that would apply best?** I'm a lay person to the field; any help is appreciated on asking my question most precisely.

Comment: Let me know if this is right: the data is one dimensional (percentage of yes votes or something) where the x-axis is time, and you want to use spectral analysis to see if there is cycles in the data, so you collect the polling answers from a website every hour or something, but there is not always new data so the underlying signal comes in "bursts".

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I tried to update my question for clarity, if not brevity. In signal processing terms, is the data is 2D if plotted on a 2-axis chart? The x-axis being time and the y-axis the sum of yeses (+1) and noes (-1). Most important for me is to understand how the data can be stored, plotted and analyzed as they are submitted. There would be uneven gaps between submissions, and no uniform sampling to get batches of answers, if possible.

Comment: That makes sense. Sounds like you realize this, but the main thing is the sampling. One more question: when a user hits "Submit" on their response, does your application get that data ASAP or does your application only check for responses say every 5 minutes? How does part work, or are you still designing that?

Comment: The data is captured in real time as the buttons are pushed. Vote tallying is just a reasonably basic use case I've invented for my own learning purposes. The same concept would apply to any interactive system that constantly feeds transactional data back to a database. The spectral analysis would occur continuously on this most atomic stream of non-integer-spaced data (without reducing it by sampling, or adding to it by interpolation or other means). I saw the tool named "NNFFT - nonequispaced in time and frequency fast Fourier transform" and thought I might be on the right track.